# Locate a function from ELF executable file

Tags: linux, linker, ld, elf

In a rather obscure use case, instead of loading the whole ELF executable file into memory, I'd like to load only the part of ELF file that contains a particular function. The difficulty I am facing is: I don't know how to locate where the code of this particular function is in the ELF file. If I had this piece of information, I would use it to load the disk sector(s) containing this part of ELF file into memory, and jump to it. But, being not very familiar with ELF file format and how `ld` works, I don't know how to get this piece of information. All the information I know is the function name (Just C function, no overload). Or, is this possible to find out the position of a function from headers of ELF file at all?

I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me some help to locate a particular function in ELF executable file. It would be perfect if I can know both its starting and ending position, but only the starting position is also fine. A reference to some reading materials towards this goal (if technically feasible at all) for self-study is also ok. The platform I am working on is `Linux 20.04` with GNU development toolchain (the version of ld is 2.34) on x86 CPU (the ELF format is `elf32−i386`).

Comment: You can get this from `nm` and `readelf`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit late, but for posterity:

Note that in the following text, most of the numbers are going to be in hexadecimal, since that's how they are output by binutils.

Code (usually?) resides in the `.text` section, so find out where that is in the ELF file: `readelf -S <ELF file>`

This should output section headers, the relevant output should look like this:

```
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
[13] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000411000  00011000
       0000000000465bac  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4096
```

Note that the address is `411000` and the offset is `11000` in the above output, so the address is `offset+400000`.

Figure out the address of your symbol: `nm -gC <ELF file> | grep <func name>`

For function `main`, this got me (among other things): `0000000000411455 T main`, which means that the function `main` is located at the address `411455`.

Since `readelf` told us that `offset=address-400000`, the code for `main` should start at byte `11455` from the start of the file.

Also note to OP: AFAIK on modern computers most memory is marked as not executable, so if you just load code into memory and jump to it, it will likely crash. There are certainly ways to allocate executable memory, but they are probably a bit more complicated than calling `malloc`.